# How to create a time range multiple times in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a table that has a time range for each id in a list, I have the following code that does it correctly but I think it is not the most efficient or pythonic, is there a better way to do it?

My code:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for id in ids:
    df_aux = pd.DataFrame(
                {'init': pd.date_range(start='2022-04-06 10:00:00', end='2022-04-06 15:00:00', freq="H"),
                 "color": "#FF0000",
                 "id": id}
            )
    df_aux['end'] = df_aux['init'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=3600)
    df = pd.concat([df,df_aux], ignore_index=True)
```

Correct result:

```
 fecha_inicio    color  id           fecha_fin
0  2022-04-06 10:00:00  #FF0000   1 2022-04-06 11:00:00
1  2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   1 2022-04-06 12:00:00
2  2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   1 2022-04-06 13:00:00
3  2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   1 2022-04-06 14:00:00
4  2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   1 2022-04-06 15:00:00
5  2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   1 2022-04-06 16:00:00
6  2022-04-06 10:00:00  #FF0000   2 2022-04-06 11:00:00
7  2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   2 2022-04-06 12:00:00
8  2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   2 2022-04-06 13:00:00
9  2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   2 2022-04-06 14:00:00
10 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   2 2022-04-06 15:00:00
11 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   2 2022-04-06 16:00:00
12 2022-04-06 10:00:00  #FF0000   3 2022-04-06 11:00:00
13 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   3 2022-04-06 12:00:00
14 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   3 2022-04-06 13:00:00
15 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   3 2022-04-06 14:00:00
16 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   3 2022-04-06 15:00:00
17 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   3 2022-04-06 16:00:00
18 2022-04-06 10:00:00  #FF0000   4 2022-04-06 11:00:00
19 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   4 2022-04-06 12:00:00
20 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   4 2022-04-06 13:00:00
21 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   4 2022-04-06 14:00:00
22 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   4 2022-04-06 15:00:00
23 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   4 2022-04-06 16:00:00
24 2022-04-06 10:00:00  #FF0000   5 2022-04-06 11:00:00
25 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   5 2022-04-06 12:00:00
26 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   5 2022-04-06 13:00:00
27 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   5 2022-04-06 14:00:00
28 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   5 2022-04-06 15:00:00
29 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   5 2022-04-06 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `concat`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"init": pd.date_range(start='2022-04-06 10:00:00', end='2022-04-06 15:00:00', freq="H"), 
                   "end": pd.date_range(start='2022-04-06 11:00:00', end='2022-04-06 16:00:00', freq="H"),
                   "color": "#FF0000"})

output = pd.concat([df.assign(id=x) for x in ids], ignore_index=True)

>>> output
                  init                 end    color  id
0  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   1
1  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   1
2  2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   1
3  2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   1
4  2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   1
5  2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   1
6  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   2
7  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   2
8  2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   2
9  2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   2
10 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   2
11 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   2
12 2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   3
13 2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   3
14 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   3
15 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   3
16 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   3
17 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   3
18 2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   4
19 2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   4
20 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   4
21 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   4
22 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   4
23 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   4
24 2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   5
25 2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   5
26 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   5
27 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   5
28 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   5
29 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   5
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this would be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
time = pd.date_range(start='2022-04-06 10:00:00',
                     end='2022-04-06 15:00:00', freq="H")
df = pd.DataFrame({'init': list(time)*len(ids),
                   'color': '#FF0000',
                   'id': sorted(ids*len(time))})
df['end'] = df['init'] + pd.Timedelta(seconds=3600)
```

No for loops are needed, multiplying a list by `x` will repeat it `x` times.  Sorting the repeated `ids` will ensure they are in the correct order (rather than `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]` they will be `[1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 2, 2, 2, ...]`).

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to create the cartesian DataFrame. I will be reusing @not_speshal's data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = pd.DataFrame({"init": pd.date_range(start='2022-04-06 10:00:00', end='2022-04-06 15:00:00', freq="H"), 
                   "end": pd.date_range(start='2022-04-06 11:00:00', end='2022-04-06 16:00:00', freq="H"),
                   "color": "#FF0000"})

ids = pd.Series(ids, name = 'id')

df.expand_grid(df_key="df", others={"id": ids}).droplevel(level=0, axis=1)

                  init                 end    color  id
0  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   1
1  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   2
2  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   3
3  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   4
4  2022-04-06 10:00:00 2022-04-06 11:00:00  #FF0000   5
5  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   1
6  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   2
7  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   3
8  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   4
9  2022-04-06 11:00:00 2022-04-06 12:00:00  #FF0000   5
10 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   1
11 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   2
12 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   3
13 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   4
14 2022-04-06 12:00:00 2022-04-06 13:00:00  #FF0000   5
15 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   1
16 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   2
17 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   3
18 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   4
19 2022-04-06 13:00:00 2022-04-06 14:00:00  #FF0000   5
20 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   1
21 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   2
22 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   3
23 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   4
24 2022-04-06 14:00:00 2022-04-06 15:00:00  #FF0000   5
25 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   1
26 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   2
27 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   3
28 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   4
29 2022-04-06 15:00:00 2022-04-06 16:00:00  #FF0000   5
```